# How to setup new git repository for mixed LF/CRLF files

Tags: git, github, freemind

I'm using GitHub Desktop on Windows 10. I want to setup a git repository which will contain some text files (.md or .adoc) and Freemind mindmaps (.mm). Freemind uses an XML-based file format with Unix-style line feeds (LF).

Over the last 4 hours, I think I have read every StackOverflow discussion and every git documentation about EOL normalisation one can find online - and it still drives me crazy! Many discussions seem to be outdated and opinions seem to contradict each other. Here's how I got so far:

- I have left `core.autocrlf` and `core.safecrlf` at their default values
- As recommended I'm using a `.gitattributes` file with `* text=auto` - I'm fine with auto conversion for my text files.
- To preserve the LF's of my .mm files I added `*.mm text eol=LF`

What's puzzling me is this warning:

```
> git add Mindmap.mm
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in Mindmap.mm.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
```

As far as I understand it `* text=auto` is equivalent to `core.autocrlf=true` and ensures that all EOL's are converted to LF at committing - So LF->LF in this case. And `*.mm text eol=LF` ensures that LF's are preserved at checkout - LF->LF in the other direction, too. No CRLF's involved! So why is Git warning me that some conversion will result in CRLF's?

**Question 1**: I'd like to make sure that I won't get cross-platform problems with UNIX users when I'll go public with my project on GitHub. What is the best practice for my case? If I did everything all right, can I ignore the warning?

**Question 2**: Under certain circumstances .mm files can also contain CRLF's. I could, of course, handle them as binary files, but then I would not see any differences in GitHub Desktop anymore. Is there a way to still treat them as text files, while preserving mixed line feeds (LF and CRLF)?

Any hint is greatly appreciated!

Comment: @Josh Yes, but, as mentioned, I'd lose diff functionality, wouldn't I?

Answer (score 2):

I don't use Windows, and therefore hesitate a bit to make recommendations, but I can describe the various mechanisms here, and make at least a few. :-)

Operations that transform file data, including anything that modifies line endings, apply (in general—there are some specific exceptions) at the time the data are extracted from the repository into the work-tree—that's basically [`git checkout`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-checkout.html), but see notes towards the end—or added into the repository, which is basically [`git add`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-add.html).

In order *to* transform file data, Git must know *which files get transformed* and *what transforms to apply*.  Git has to classify each file to decide what to do.

Some files are clearly binary, some are almost certainly text, and some are quite ambiguous.  Git will guess if it has to.  You can (and I guess, perhaps, used to have to?) *tell* it to guess by setting `core.autocrlf=true` or `core.autocrlf=input`, but see the next paragraph.

If you have a `.gitattributes` file, you can tell Git about files based on their path names, e.g., that `*.txt` should always be treated as text files and `*.bin` files should never be treated as text files.  This gives you much finer control, because not only can you match based on path names like this, you can also write any of these:

```
*.ex1   text      # definitely text
*.ex2   -text     # definitely not text
*.ex3   text=auto # please guess for me based on file contents
# don't mention *.ex4: check core.autocrlf to decide whether to guess
```

Just based on this part, I would suggest that `core.autocrlf` is never good to use, because guessing seems suspect in the first place.  At least with `text=auto` you have an obvious place *requesting* the guessing, though.

Independent of the guess-or-definite, you can list `eol=crlf` or `eol=lf` after a path.  This enables conversion, i.e., the file is treated as if it were text when it comes to deciding whether to mess with line endings on extraction (`git checkout`) and insertion (`git add`).  What winds up in the work-tree is either CRLF or LF-only.  In either case CRLF in the work-tree is replaced with LF-only during `git add`.  I suspect, but *have not tested*, that this *does not* affect `git diff`.

(The old `crlf`, `-crlf`, and `crlf=input` settings should no doubt no longer be used, but if you do use them, they act as described in [the `gitattributes` documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitattributes.html).)

Now, the obvious problem you've highlighted is that using `-text` to mark a file as "never touch with autocrlf or other guessed-at transformations" interacts with `git diff`, because `git diff` *also* has to guess whether a file is text, before producing a diff.  Here, we can go back to [the `gitattributes` documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitattributes.html), where we find that path names can have a `diff` attribute:

```
*.ex5   -text diff  # not text for crlf treatment, but text for diff
*.ex6   -text -diff # not text for either one
*.ex7   text -diff  # definitely text for crlf, but binary for diff
*.ex8   diff=my-diff-driver # use my diff driver; no opinion about text
```

Leaving out `diff` entirely makes Git guess, just as it does with crlf treatment.

Note that path names in `.gitattributes` need not be patterns: you can list:

```
path/to/some/file       -text
path/to/another/file    text
```

in case Git guesses wrong about some files.

I have not yet mentioned `core.safecrlf`, but I think the discussion in [the `git config` documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-config.html) is pretty adequate here.  It consists of a bunch of special tests run during various commands, doing conversions in *both* directions a bit early, with the final checkout stage going to a temporary file that is immediately thrown out, just to see if files that are in the work-tree *right now* would stay the *way* they are right now.  That is, if you did a `git add path; git commit -m dummy; rm path; git checkout -- path` *right now*, would the file in *path* change contents?  If so, the conversion is not "safe".

Last, I should mention a few more special cases.  Conversions (both line endings and smudge filters) are done any time the file comes out of the index; this includes [the `git checkout-index`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-checkout-index.html) command.  They can also be done on purpose during operations that bypass the index: [`git cat-file`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-cat-file.html), by adding `--textconv` or `--path=` or `--filters`; [`git show`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-show.html), with `--textconv`, although the details vary a bit based on specific Git version (many of these options are not in older versions of Git).  Similarly, conversions (line endings and clean filters) are done any time the file goes into the index, but can also be done or suppressed in [`git hash-object`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-hash-object.html), using `--path` or `--no-filters`.

Comment: Very enlightening, thanks a lot! So in my case I'd choose `*.mm -text diff` to prevent crlf conversion but treat it as text for diffs (assuming Freemind on Windows produces the same file format as Freemind on other systems). What's still puzzling me, though, is the warning (described above) Git gives me. Your explanations seem to confirm that with `*.mm text eol=LF` there are no CRLF's involved. Would you be willing to guess about that?

Comment: This is certainly confusing. It appears that `eol=LF` overrides any `text` or `-text`, but it should (per documentation) mean "replace CRLF with LF when adding blob, leave alone when extracting to work-tree". This is quite the opposite of the warning that comes out. I could dig through the Git source for your particular Git version (if it's not hacked-up-for-Windows; some Windows distributions are; they add their own bugs :-) ) to try to see why the warning comes out. (The `core.safecrlf` setting defaults to `warn`.)

Comment: GitHub desktop comes with a version of PortableGit. `git --version` gives `git version 2.11.0.windows.3` Do you need additional info?

Comment: Hm, that does mean it's a version modified for windows.  I can look into plain 2.11.0, but before I do, it might be interesting to try this same repository on a system that has 2.11.0 and see if it emits the same warning.

Answer (score 1):

Unsetting `text` for `.mm` files will stop git from doing `crlf` conversions on them but it won't start treating them as binary files so git-diff and other features will still behave correctly.

#### In your .gitattributes file:

```
* text=auto

*.mm -text
```

That should solve your second question. However, because git won't be enforcing the line endings for `.mm` files it likely will cause some headaches when you go public and contributors start modifying them on OS-X and Linux. If you can describe the rules for `.mm` line endings maybe the config can be tweaked or perhaps a commit-hook can help you enforce it, other than that I don't see how you can solve both your first and second questions at the same time.